# Can I make a python package depend on different packages by OS?

Tags: python, setuptools, python-wheel

I'm working on a package that requires [`sh`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh/). This package is not supported on Windows. For Windows, I use the old package `sh` was forked from, [`pbs`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pbs), and rename it to `sh` in my namespace.

How can I create a `setup.py` that will properly install `pbs` on Windows and `sh` on other platforms?

**EDIT:** After some research, it turns out my question was specific to the new [wheel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel) format as [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21371595/429533) reflects. I'll ask a different question in the future if I can't figure out how wheels are supposed to work.

Comment: check something like `sys.platform` before calling setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it turns out my original solution **was** correct:

```
# setup.py
...
setup(
...

    install_requires=["pbs" if os.name == 'nt' else "sh"]
...
)
```

The reason this recently broke was due to releasing in the new [wheel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel) format. My understanding is that this new format does not ship a `setup.py` with your package and handles dependencies using some other means.

Until I understand how to ship a wheel with conditional dependencies, I just won't produce wheels for this project.

Answer (score 3):

Yes!  Just put your code in a conditional block on the sys.platform variable such as:

```
import sys
if (sys.platform=='win32'):
    import somewindowsmodule
elif (sys.platform=='macOSX'):
    import somemacmodule
elif (sys.platform=='linux'):
    import somelinuxmodule
```

I'm not sure what the platform strings are for mac or linux, but you can figure that out, I'm sure.  Also, the somemodule names are all fictitious to protect the innocent.  :)

Comment: Are you suggesting this code goes in `setup.py`? My question is about installation dependencies.